# How to add files to already pushed commit in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have commited and pushed some changes and forgot to add 2 files to that commit. Since that commit, I have commited a number of commits, so there are many commits between the commit I want to change/add the file to and the HEAD. I need something like interactive rebasing and fixup, just in IntelliJ IDEA. So my question is, how can I add these 2 files to that commit in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Am I right to assume this is git? And is there a particular reason you can't just push these files in a new commit?

Comment: Yes it's git, I forgot to mention that sorry. For now I just pushed them in a new one, but for good overview I want them to be in the same commit.

Comment: I'd recommend you don't do any heavy lifting in git like squashing commits in intellij or any IDE. You want to use the CLI for this.  I don't know if you even can... 

Having said that, _before_ you pursue this plan you *must* understand editing history can be dangerous.

Where did you push it? is it on a feature branch? is it to master? a fork?

Comment: Ok I have already thought that. Yea I already noticed that rebasing can be dangerous x.x It's a feature branch I am working on. So I think I'll just keep using the CLI, but thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should notice that changing the history of a published branch might be dangerous. If anyone else is using the same branch this could lead to a confusing history with duplicate commits.

However if you would otherwise do that using the CLI you might also use IntelliJ to do so if you prefer the GUI way.

### Amending the previous commit

If you need to add these two files to the last commit, you can just amend your changes to that commit. To do so start committing like you would do to create a new commit. In the commit window check the box next to "Amend commit". IntelliJ will then automatically fill the field "Commit Message" with the message of the last commit. After committing the changes there will be only one commit containing the changes of the previous commit and your recent changes.

### Rebasing

You can even do interactive rebasing using the IntelliJ GUI to change the history. The option "Rebase..." can be found in the menu "VCS" in the submenu "Git". In the opening dialog you can select "Interactive" to do interactive rebasing. You also need to select a branch or commit to rebase onto. This might be the branch your branch is based onto or the last commit in your history you don't want to change. The opening dialog gives you the same options as the interactive rebase of the CLI. See the documentation example for Interactive rebase for the available options. To add changes to a previous commit you might want to have a look at the section "Squashing multiple commits into one".

### Pushing your changes

To push these changes you first need to configure IntelliJ to allow force push. This option can be found in the preferences under "Version Control" > "Git", where you can check "Allow force push". After doing so hovering over the "Push" button in the bottom right of the Push dialog opens a dropdown with an entry "Force push". You need to use that to push your changed commit to the remote repository.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer. I would have one more question: Why do duplicate commits occur when I change the history of a published branch? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: That doesn't happen in every case. It might happen if someone else has a local copy of that branch and just pulls your new version, which woul create a merge commit with both histories (the original one and the rewritten one) as parents.